# How to set up git to use ssh instead of https?

Tags: github, ssh

> $ git remote -v
>
> origin  https://github.com/my-repo/site-web.git (fetch)
>
> origin  https://github.com/my-repo/site-web.git (push)

I have ssh set up and a shell script to run like this:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
git reset --hard
...
git pull
```

But I still get prompted for a password. I assume the remote needs to be git@github.com for the ssh to work.

I have four directories... `a/` `b/` `c/` and `d/` and all of them point to this remote. But I really only want ssh to work in `a/`. I'm happy to keep using https for the others.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

If a/ is a git repo, you can simply change its remote:

```
cd a
git remote set-url origin git@github.com/my-repo/site-web.git
```

But if `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are folder of the same repo, that would change origin for all of them.

To have ssh only for `a/`, you would need a [separate clone, as a sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/6309), in order to work only with `a/` content (and have the right remote url for that separate clone).

Comment: Hi, yes all folders point to the same repo. Basically it's the same code in each but a different database. I just tried what you suggested and it did indeed change the remote for all of them. There's no way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your .ssh/id_rsa.pub to you github account.